# Why is a ref parameter type different to the regular type?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, language-design, pass-by-reference

I understand how to go between the 2 different types but my question is; why is this difference **at the type level**?

I would have thought it would be a property of the [`ParamterInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.aspx) object, not separate special type.

Assuming it's presented as a separate type in reflection because that is how it is internally, what language benefits are there to having this as a separate type (I'm guessing easier method overload resolution or something)?

On a similar note, why does `ref` make a distinct type but `out` doesn't (I can't think of reasons for `ref` being a separate type, that don't apply to `out`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static int SomeMethod(string local, ref string strParam)
{
  local = SomeStaticlyHeldString;
  strParam = SomeStaticlyHeldString;
  int localInt = local.Length;
  return strParam.Length;
}
```

The assignment to `local` means that the place in memory that `local` labels now points to the same object that `SomeStaticlyHeldString` was pointing to.

The assignment to `strParam` means that the place in memory that the argument passed to the method using `ref` labels, now points to the same object that `SomeStaticlyHeldString` was pointing to.

Obtaining `local.Length` queries the object that `local` points to. Obtaining `strParam.Length` queries the object that the variable that `strParam` points to, points to.

The two are really behaving very differently, not just at the point the parameter or local is defined, but with every use of them. That the difference is largely hidden makes them all the more different, as every operation upon them differs in effect.

If we had a lower level language that had nothing but local variables, objects on some sort of non-local heap, and pointers to both of those, then `local` would be of type `string*` and `strParam` of type `string**`. This would be how we would do a similar sort of operation in C, and how we could do so in C++ though it also has reference types (though with C++ that a type is a reference type is more clearly part of its type definition, and they have further uses and refinements). C# hides almost all of this from us in its syntax. It's always debatable how beneficial any hiding of details is, but in this case there isn't much in the way of anything useful being hidden, so it's one that one would be hard-pressed to criticise.

Comment: Accepting this one as IMO it better answers my question. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 6):

`ref` parameters have distinct types because `ref` types are also allowed and useful in other contexts than parameters. C# doesn't allow it, but other languages (at least C++/CLI) do support, for example, local variables of reference type. Such a thing makes sense for `ref`, but not for `out`.

Pretending C# allows it, you could write (it's supported by IL):

```
int x = 3;
ref int y = x;
y = 4;
if (x == 4)
    MessageBox.Show("x is 4");
```

This isn't an example of when it's *useful*, but in the same situations where `ref` parameters are useful, it can also be useful to use a helper class or struct with a `ref` field.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. An example would be helpful though. I can't see how you'd use a ref local.

Comment: Updated with an admittedly useless example :)

Comment: Ahh i see, still not too sure of an actual application though. Guess you could have y referring to one of several variables or something (or elements in an array?).

Comment: Another thing is, ref is useful for interop, as ref will behave as a pointer when passed in unmanaged code. out on the other hand can't be used with interop.

Comment: Yes, in C++/CLI you can write `int% z = foo() ? x : y;`, and `z` will refer to either `x` or `y`, depending on what `foo()` returned.

Comment: It's worth bearing in mind that in C++, whether an object is allocated locally on the stack or on the heap is not-related to the type of the ultimate object, but related to how the object is created by the programmer. There is hence not the "value type" and "reference type" distinction of classes and structs, but of how they are used in a given case. C++/CLI has a mixture of both this and the .NET approach.

Comment: One example of a ref _return type_ function that C# does use even if you can't define it in C# yourself is the Address function on arrays, which allows you to take the address of (for purposes of passing to a ref argument) a multidimensional array element.